# can not implement SNMP class in PHP

Tags: php, snmp, net-snmp

I want to use snmp class on PHP, and try that [example-1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.get.php) on my server.

```
<?php
  $session = new SNMP(SNMP::VERSION_1, "127.0.0.1", "public");
  $sysdescr = $session->get("sysDescr.0");
  echo "$sysdescr\n";
  $sysdescr = $session->get(array("sysDescr.0"));
  print_r($sysdescr);
?>
```

when I execute this I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SNMP' not found in /var/www/wls/wtest.php on line 2
```

I installed snmp and php with yum:

```
yum install httpd php php-devel php-snmp net-snmp
```

I also tried to find cause but i found just about library and my server info:

php-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64 php-snmp-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64 net-snmp-5.5-41.el6_3.1.x86_64

I think the reason must be so simple but I couldn't found it,
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SNMP class is only available in PHP 5.4 and higher, for PHP 5.3 and lower and you have to use the SNMP functions instead, http://php.net/manual/en/ref.snmp.php.

Answer (score 0):

1. Restart Apache.
2. Check that `php-snmp.so` is listed in `extensions.ini`.
3. Check if there's a section for php-snmp in `phpinfo()`.
4. Check your server's logs.